# In Pages, how to edit these immovable (but not locked) images?

Tags: pages

Sometimes I import a Microsoft Word file into Pages, only to find that some portion of the document is not editable. Usually an image that is treated like part of the background, and although it can be highlighted, it cannot be unlocked from the Arrange menu. So it must not be a *locked* object, but something else.

Here is a visual reference:

[image: This Apple Pages object is selectable, but not editable]

While selected, this is what the **Arrange** menu looks like. "**Lock**", and most other items are greyed out:

[image]

What's happening in cases like this, and how can I edit the object?

**Notes:**

Enabling **Make Layout Objects Selectable** has not changed the behavior. I'm not even sure that it is a "layout object".

The Pages version is **12.1**

Comment: Which version of Pages? I think this can happen when images or other elements are - or become on import - part of a section layout. Select the object, then choose *Arrange > Section Layouts > Make Layout Objects Selectable* and see wether this solves the problem.

Comment: @slartibartfast Thanks for the suggestion. I too wondered if *Make Layout Objects Selectable* might allow the object to be edited. But it does not appear to have changed anything. It was selectable before and after enabling that (by click-drag only) - but not editable. The version is 12.1. I have updated the question to include these details.

Comment: So if you switch into page layout this element can’t be edited? If so, can you check wether this is an text anchored image? Try to unlock via the Arrange menu in the Menu bar - then check the Inspector. Such images in imported word documents should, when selected, show small grey x instead of the normal small white squares as resize handles. But this doesn’t seem to work all the time. What happens if you double-click such image?